# How to build vertical data form in Symfony2, where fields are key-value rows?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Lets say I got some kind of metadata table.

```
| ID | Key  | Value  | Data Type | Label |
|----|------|--------|-----------|-------|
| 1  | key1 | value1 | text      | ...   |
| 2  | key2 | value2 | boolean   | ...   |
| 3  | key3 | value3 | file      | ...   |
| 4  | ...  | ...    | ...       | ...   |
```

And it should be displayd as form using Symfony2 Form component and Doctrine2 ORM:

```
<form>
 <label>{{ label1 }}</label><input type="text" name="{{ key1 }}" value="{{ value1 }}">
 <label>{{ label2 }}</label><input type="checkbox" name="{{ key2 }}" value="1">
 <label>{{ label3 }}</label><input type="file" name="{{ key3 }}" value="{{ value3 }}">
</form>
```

Comment: did you got any solution for above use case?

Answer (score 0):

That is enough to get started :-)

```
 {% for x in xy %}

 <label>{{ x.label }}</label>
 <input type="
    {% if x.datatype == "boolean" %}
          checkbox
    {% else %}
          {{ x.datatype }}
    {% endif %}
  " name="{{ x.key }}" value="{{ x.value }}">

 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: My question was actually a bit different. I specified the question. How to do it using Symfony2 Form and Doctrine ORM.

Comment: oh sorry.. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html   this might be usefull, with PRESET you can check the value of column and based on this you can add form elements.. so if value if value is file you can add ->add("something", "file", null)  etc.. it will be nice and dynamic